# How do I use php to upload and rename multiple files using a dropdown menu for the file names?

Tags: php, file-upload, rename, bulk

I need to allow users to upload multiple files and then choose the filename using a drop-down menu.  The files will be used for my schools 'options' website and the files need to be named using course codes.  Unfortunately, users often misname so I want to allow them to upload files and select the course.  The plan is to automatically rename them so that the code is correct.  Users select their name and then upload files so that their uploads go in a dedicated folder.

I can do it for one file but I need to be able to do it for more than one file.  I can upload multiple files but can't seem to rename them.  The problem is that I don't know how to link multiple new file names to the array that can be created using $_FILES

Here's the code for uploading and renaming a single file (it uses .jpg files but will be changed to .pdf files in due course) ...

```html
<?php 

// Makes directory and changes file name for one file

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 
 $uploads = $_POST['name'];
 if (!is_dir($uploads))
 {
  mkdir($uploads);
 }
 
 $info = pathinfo($_FILES['userFile']['name']);
 $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
 $newname = $_POST['new_name'].".".$ext; 

 $target = $uploads.'/'.$newname;
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $target);
 
}
?>

<form name="UploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    
    <p>
    Find the file(s) you want to upload and click the "Upload" button below.
 </p>
 <p>
 <b>Teacher Code:</b> 
  <select name="name">
   <option value="Mr_A">Mr A</option>
   <option value="Mr_B">Mr_B</option>
   <option value="Mr_C">Mr C</option>
  </select>
 </p>
 
 <p>Select the course from the box and then select the .pdf outline...</p>

    
  <p>
  
  <select name="new_name">
   <option value="">Choose...</option>
   <option value="L1PROG01">Programming - Level 1</option>
   <option value="L2PROG01">Programming - Level 2</option>
   <option value="L3PROG01">Programming - Level 3</option>
   <option value="L1WEBD01">Web Design - Level 1</option>
   <option value="L2WEBD01">Web Design - Level 2</option>
   <option value="L3WEBD01">Web Design - Level 3</option>
  </select>
  
  <input name="userFile" type="file" />
  
  </p>
  
    <br/>Check this box <input autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" checked name="overwrite" /> to <strong>overwrite</strong> existing files.
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html

`<input name="files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />`

PHP

```
$count = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {    

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i]);
$newfilename = "new_name". '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], "upload/" . $newfilename);

}
```

Comment: Sorry- the above does not work for me.  It moves the files to the 'uploads' folder but calls the file 'new_name.jpg' <and of course there will only be one file in the folder as it has been set up to overwrite files with the same name>.  The good news is that it renames files.  The bad news is that I still don't know how to rename the file so that it matches the value my users selected from the drop-down menu.

Comment: add some rand() number with that new name, if you provide same name for all the fill will replace

Comment: The code you gave me was great - it was just missing a bit in the html (the square brackets after 'new_name').  I also tweaked the php so that it gets both the file name and the file from the form that my users fill out.  I've posted the working code below in case others have a similar problem.  I needed to have different names for my files which made things a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I used Mani's code (which helped a lot) and it now works.  Here is the key bit...

html:

```html
 <p>Select the course from the box and then select the .pdf outline...</p>

  <?php
  for ($n=0; $n<10; $n++) {
  ?>
  <p>
    
  <select name="new_name[<?php $n ?>]" value="">
   <option value="">Choose...</option>
   <option value="L1PROG01">Programming - Level 1</option>
   <option value="L2PROG01">Programming - Level 2</option>
   <option value="L3PROG01">Programming - Level 3</option>
   <option value="L1WEBD01">Web Design - Level 1</option>
   <option value="L2WEBD01">Web Design - Level 2</option>
   <option value="L3WEBD01">Web Design - Level 3</option>
  </select>
```

and here is the updated php (which is towards the top of the page)

```html
<?php 

// Makes directory and changes file name for many files.  

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 
 $uploads = $_POST['name']; // folder name
  
 if (!is_dir($uploads))
 {
  mkdir($uploads);
 }
 
 $count = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

 for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {    

 $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i]);
 $new_name = $_POST['new_name'][$i];
 $newfilename = $new_name. '.' . end($temp);
 $target = $uploads.'/'.$new_name.".jpg";
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target);

 }
  
 }

?>
```

The above makes a folder depending on the teachers' name and then allows them to upload their files (renaming them correctly).  It will automatically over write old files which is what I want it to do.  It does not *yet* invalid / unexpected data.